# For each value of variable, select only those containing all values from list. R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, vector

I have a large data set with many columns, including week number (i.e., 1, 2, 3) and weekday ("Monday", "Tuesday", etc). Some weeks may only have data for one or two weekdays. I need to select or flag only the weeks with "complete" data, that is, at least one Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday.

I tried to make a for loop that, for each week number, would test if the week contains at least one of each element in the list "weekdays." I made a new column that would flag each week that meets that requirement (here, week 1). However, the for loop is not working as intended because all flags returned are "0" whereas I expect "1" for week 1.

```
week_num <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
day <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Friday", "Sunday", "Saturday", "Thursday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday", "Sunday")

reprex <- data.frame(cbind(week_num, day))

weekdays <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday")

for (i in unique(reprex$week_num)){
  reprex$flag = if_else(all(reprex$day %in% weekdays), 1, 0)
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help; I recognize that I am missing something obvious/ that there is likely a better way to do this. Cheers

Comment: Careful with your use of `cbind` here, which outputs a matrix that will coerce `week_num` to character in `reprex`.

Comment: @LMc thank you for not only answering my question but explaining the 'why' behind it! Yes, that makes total sense and I will use this understanding going forward. Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using the `dplyr` package:

```r
library(dplyr)

reprex |>
  mutate(flag = all(weekdays %in% day), .by = week_num)
```

**Output**

```
   week_num       day  flag
1         1    Monday  TRUE
2         1   Tuesday  TRUE
3         1  Thursday  TRUE
4         1 Wednesday  TRUE
5         1    Friday  TRUE
6         2    Friday FALSE
7         2    Sunday FALSE
8         2  Saturday FALSE
9         3  Thursday FALSE
10        3 Wednesday FALSE
11        3   Tuesday FALSE
12        3    Sunday FALSE
```

---

About your attempt here are a few things to consider:

You are looping through `unique(reprex$week_num)`, but within your `for` loop you are not doing anything with your indexing variable `i`. So each iteration of your `for` you are running the same expression repeatedly:

```
if_else(all(reprex$day %in% weekdays), 1, 0)
```

Taking a look at what this expression is doing from the inside out:

```r
# 1. Testing if reprex$day is found in vector weekdays
reprex$day %in% weekdays
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

# 2. Test if every logical value is TRUE (which it is not)
all(reprex$day %in% weekdays)
[1] FALSE

# 3. Always returning FALSE then if_else returns 0
if_else(FALSE, 1, 0)
[1] 0
```